# Mac Mouse can be found but no longer connects

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

For a couple or so months my Mac sometimes doesn't connect to my Magic Mouse when I boot the computer. Generally it will connect when I reboot.  Now, however, it doesn't connect to my mouse at all.  (I'm using a generic USB mouse at the moment.) I removed the mouse from my Bluetooth connections and tried to create a new Bluetooth mouse connection. My Mac finds the mouse and displays it sometimes as a series of double digits separated by colons and sometimes as "Mike's Mouse."  But even though it finds the mouse, when I click "connect," it simply doesn't happen. I get nothing but a spinning symbol, and the computer will not connect to the mouse.

So what might the issue be?  Do I need a new mouse? A computer repair? How can I know?

Comment: And, since you don't mention this ... you are sure the mouse's battery is charged aren't you?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What is your Mac model and what version of macOS do you have? Could you test the mouse with another computer and report back?